# Check to see if any files aren't being accessed in website

Tags: php

I've inherited a somewhat large web application which is a total mess in terms of code and has zero comments. I want to start by removing all the files that aren't actually being used. Is there a quicker way to do this than trawl through each file looking for calls?

I know dreamweaver can do this but I really don't want to go that route...

Comment: You can automate a process to parse through each filename and then parse the logs from the past month or whatever.

Comment: @jraede - a good start; but you'll also need to make sure that the files aren't being included in other files - the included files won't appear in the logs.

Comment: Correct, if you have anything beyond simple HTML pages you should do that as well. I missed the "web application" and the "php" tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try eclipse. I think i saw there some profiler and try this get_included_files

Answer (score 0):

On linux, use the stat command. Write a script to iterate over your files using the stat command. This will give you the last access time.

```
$ stat testdisk.log 
  File: `testdisk.log'
  Size: 1014        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 805h/2053d  Inode: 1448800     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2012-07-21 17:20:33.548997182 +0530
Modify: 2011-08-16 23:27:19.648480473 +0530
Change: 2011-08-16 23:27:19.648480473 +0530
```

To find included files you can also use PHPs built in function:

```
array get_included_files ( void )
```